# Designing APIs in Flask with blueprints

Tags: python, api, flask

I'm trying to wrap my head around proper API design in flask. My original design was to build an API blueprint that was a thin layer to bridge the URL endpoint to the actual API logic like below.

```
@api.route('/posts/<int:id>')
def get_post(id):
    return apiLogic.get_post(id)
```

I assumed this would be the best way to design the API because if I needed to query a post from jQuery on the client, I could use the `/posts/<int:id>` endpoint. Additionally, if I needed to render a page with a specific post from the backend, my backend code could directly call apiLogic.get_post(id) without having to do a http request to `/posts/<int:id>` (essentially sending an HTTP request to itself).

However, I believe that since the API is a blueprint, I can not directly call `apiLogic.get_post(id)` in the backend and retain the blueprint_before_request authorization checks since I'm not calling this function through the blueprint per se.

I could resolve this problem by not calling the functions directly and instead using an http request when my backend wants to get a post, but is that bad design? What is the best way to structure an API in flask that can be used both by the client and the server?

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar with my web applications. I'm guessing by authorization you mean permission checks, not authentication. The way I'd handle this is moving the authorization layer out of the view layer and into the business logic layer (apiLogic).

I usually attach my authorization layer to business logic using decorators. You could still use decorators for your authorization layer and decorate your view functions but you'll have to do it twice (once for each corresponding method in the REST api and the Web frontend)